# I am getting error throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event when try to install NYC code coverage tool using terminal

Tags: code-coverage

I am installing NYC code coverage tool and setting report path, getting "throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event" when try to set up.

I am hitting following command and getting above error

NODE_ENV=TEST APPLICATION=TEST VAULT_ROLE_ID=$TEST VAULT_SECRET_ID=$TEST  VAULT_PATH=TEST PORT=1234 /usr/local/bin/nyc cover --report=json-summary --report=html --report=text node $LOCATION_OF_APP.js